# Schedule primefaces dialog

Tags: primefaces

Schedule component.I can see the schedule but not see p:dialog component when I click on a day.
code of the controller:

```
public class ScheduleController implements Serializable {
  private ScheduleModel eventModel;
  private ScheduleEvent event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
  public ScheduleController() {
    eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
    eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Champions League Match", previousDay8Pm(), previousDay11Pm()));
    eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Birthday Party", today1Pm(), today6Pm()));
    eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Breakfast at Tiffanys", nextDay9Am(), nextDay11Am()));
    eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Plant the new garden stuff", theDayAfter3Pm(), fourDaysLater3pm()));
  }

  public Date getRandomDate(Date base) {
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.setTime(base);
    date.add(Calendar.DATE, ((int) (Math.random()*30)) + 1);    //set random day of month   
    return date.getTime();
  }

  public Date getInitialDate() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.FEBRUARY, calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), 0, 0, 0); 
    return calendar.getTime();
  }

  public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
    return eventModel;
  }

  private Calendar today() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), 0, 0, 0);
    return calendar;
  }

  private Date previousDay8Pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) - 1);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8);    
    return t.getTime();
  }

  private Date previousDay11Pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) - 1);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);       
    return t.getTime();
  }

  private Date today1Pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 1);    
    return t.getTime();
  }

  private Date theDayAfter3Pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 2);     
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3);    
    return t.getTime();
  }

  private Date today6Pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone(); 
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 6);    
    return t.getTime();
  }

  private Date nextDay9Am() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 1);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);    
    return t.getTime();
  }

  private Date nextDay11Am() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 1);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);   
    return t.getTime();
  }

  private Date fourDaysLater3pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone(); 
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 4);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3);
    return t.getTime();
  }

  public ScheduleEvent getEvent() {
    return event;
  }

  public void setEvent(ScheduleEvent event) {
    this.event = event;
  }

  public void addEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if(event.getId() == null)
      eventModel.addEvent(event);
    else
      eventModel.updateEvent(event);    
    event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
  }

  public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    event = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();
  }

  public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    event = new DefaultScheduleEvent("", (Date) selectEvent.getObject(), (Date) selectEvent.getObject());
  }

  public void onEventMove(ScheduleEntryMoveEvent event) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event moved", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());    
    addMessage(message);
  }

  public void onEventResize(ScheduleEntryResizeEvent event) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event resized", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());  
    addMessage(message);
  }

  private void addMessage(FacesMessage message) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
  }
}
```

and here the code of the the .xhtml:

```
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

<p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{scheduleController.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule">

    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{scheduleController.onDateSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show()" />
    <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show()" />
    <p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventMove}" update="messages" />
    <p:ajax event="eventResize" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventResize}" update="messages" />

</p:schedule>

<p:dialog widgetVar="eventDialog" header="Event Details" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">
    <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel for="title" value="Title:" />
        <p:inputText id="title" value="#{scheduleController.event.title}" required="true"/>

        <h:outputLabel for="from" value="From:" />
        <p:inputMask id="from" value="#{scheduleController.event.startDate}" mask="99/99/9999">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
        </p:inputMask>

        <h:outputLabel for="to" value="To:" />
        <p:inputMask id="to" value="#{scheduleController.event.endDate}" mask="99/99/9999">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
        </p:inputMask>

        <h:outputLabel for="allDay" value="All Day:" />
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="allDay" value="#{scheduleController.event.allDay}" />

        <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />
        <p:commandButton id="addButton" value="Save" actionListener="#{scheduleController.addEvent}" oncomplete="PF('myschedule').update();PF('eventDialog').hide();"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: the problem is :the dialog pop up don't show i do not know why